# Remove css class if element is empty with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables that hold images throughout my document. Each table has 3 rows (Caption/Image/Source). I need to style my caption to have a border using CSS, but when the caption is blank, the caption class still appears in my markup, resulting in a random border appearing.

Table with caption:

```
<table class="img-include">
  <tr>
    <td class="caption">My Caption </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="image"><img src="..." /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="source">My Source</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Table with no caption, with the class="caption" still in the table cell:

```
<table class="img-include">
  <tr>
    <td class="caption"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="img"><img src="..." /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="source">My Source</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove the caption class for cells that are empty, but my current JS removes the class for all my elements:

```
//remove empty caption
if ($('.caption').is(':empty')){
  $("td").removeClass( ".caption" );
}
```

How can I update this so it only removes the class for empty .caption cells

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5dq63zL4/

Comment: Your .caption will return an iterable of all elements that match that class; you'd need to loop over them all to check if empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the class with JS, you can use the CSS pseudo-class [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) with [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), to style only non empty captions:

```css
table {
  margin: 20px 0
}

.caption:not(:empty) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.source {
  font-size: .85em;
  color: #777
}
```

```html
<table class="img-include">
  <tr>
    <td class="caption">My Caption </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="source">My Source</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table class="img-include">
  <tr>
    <td class="caption"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="source">My Source</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table class="img-include">
  <tr>
    <td class="caption">My Caption </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="source">My Source</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

very easy

```
td.caption:empty{
  border:none
}
```